# Change Data Attribute json value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change specific value of json array. for detail i have this dom :

```
<input class="fileupload" type="file" data-form-data='{"table_reference": "data_monitoring", "table_token" : "X43sd"}'>
```

i know how to update the data attribute using jquery using this code :  *$(this).attr('key', 'value')*

but how to change specific key in data attribute, for example on above dom
I need to change the **table_token** value

thank for any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.data()` with property reference to set the specific property to a value

```js
$(".fileupload").data().formData.table_token = 123;

console.log($(".fileupload").data().formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="fileupload" type="file" data-form-data='{"table_reference": "data_monitoring", "table_token" : "X43sd"}'>
```

If requirement is to set `data-*` which will be reflected in HTML you can use `HTMLElement.dataset`

```
var new_token = "abc";

let data = JSON.parse($(".fileupload")[0].dataset.formData);

data.table_token = new_token;

$(".fileupload")[0].dataset.formData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: I think you mean `.data().formData.table_token`

Comment: @navotera Not sure what you mean? The property is set at the `.data()` object

Comment: please check my fiddle

Comment: Yes, the `.data()` is set at the jsfiddle

Comment: sorry table_token value never changed when i click 'save' button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156607/discussion-between-navotera-and-guest271314).